# javascript RegEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string "rb40425,Fri Jan 30 11:35:33 2015@ot7293,Fri Jan...."

I would like to use the javascript RegEX to only get the user name such as rb40425 and ot7293 and on and on.

this is what i currently have:

replace(/,.*/, "");

That only returns the first user name.

Comment: How do you know what a user name is?

Comment: would `/[a-z]{2}\d+/g` work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=,|$)/g
```

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Matches one or more alphabets or digts.
- `(?=,)` Checks if the matched characters in above pattern is followed by `,` or end of string `$`.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iR4yL9/1)

**Example**

```
var string = "rb40425,Fri Jan 30 11:35:33 2015@ot7293,Fri Jan....";
console.log( string.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=,|$)/g));
// => ["rb40425", "ot7293"]

string = "d7922,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,Tue Mar 4 17:29:42 2014@rr7323,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922";
console.log( string.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=,|$)/g));
// => ["d7922", "ld7922", "rr7323", "ld7922"]
```

Comment: so i am still not able to show more than two user when i have an output like this: d7922,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,Tue Mar 4 17:29:42 2014@rr7323,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,

Comment: @ReazurRahman That was a small glitch from my part. Fixed by adding `$`. See the second example.

Comment: so seems like my column that i am outputting the match too isn't big enough to show all of the users is there a way to show just the first 4 character. like dl79, ld79, rr73, ld79.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at each `@` symbol and then `.map()` the array of users to a new array of just the user names using the `/,.*$/` regular expression to match eveything from the comma onwards.

Like this:

```
var str = "rb40425,Fri Jan 30 11:35:33 2015@ot7293,Fri Jan....";
var users = str.split('@')
               .map( function(x){ return x.replace( /,.*$/, '' ); } );
console.log( users.join('\n') );
```

If you don't want to split the string then you can use:

```
var users = str.replace( /,.*?(@|$)/g, ',' );
console.log( users );
```

This will replace each comma and all the following characters (but as few as possible) until it either finds an `@` symbol or the end of the string.

Comment: so i am still not able to show more than two user when i have an output like this: d7922,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,Tue Mar 4 17:29:42 2014@rr7323,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,

Comment: `var str = "d7922,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,Tue Mar 4 17:29:42 2014@rr7323,Tue Mar 4 17:28:45 2014@ld7922,";
var users = str.split('@').map( function(x){ return x.replace( /,.*$/, '' ); } );
console.log( users.join('\n') );` outputs 4 users and so does the second method I posted.

Comment: actually it's only out putting the first two users. I will try to attach a screen shot.